# Grammar and be verbs

Tags: verbs, headlinese

> Sam and I at the club.

Or

> Sam and I are at the club.

Which one is correct

1. for a photo caption?
2. when someone says "where are you?"

Comment: It might be useful to note also that an AP style rule for captions is that those  that are not complete sentences shouldn't be punctuated at the end, while those that are should be. So *Sam and I at the club* and *Sam and I are at the club.* are correct.

Answer (score 4):

The first option is not a complete sentence, but it is appropriate for a photo caption. A photo caption is usually just a label, not a complete sentence.

If you were carrying the photo and wanted to show it to somebody, you would say out loud "**This is** Sam and me at the club." But with a label, such as you put on photos or containers, the object and verb of such a sentence ("This" and "Is") are implied but not written. For example, if you were labeling a bag of rice, it would just say "Rice" on it, not "This is rice."

Note that it should actually be "Sam and me," not "Sam and I" for the photo, because the personal pronoun is the subject of the implied verb. If you wanted to label a photo of just your face without any modifiers or other people in the group, you would caption it "Me," not "I."

The second option is appropriate as an answer to the question "Where are you?" because it is a complete spoken sentence that includes subjects ("Sam and I") as well as a verb construction ("are at the club").